# Copy a file from local drive to share drive using JCIFS performance issue

Tags: java, jcifs

I am using the following JCIFS code to copy a file from local disk to shared drive

```
public boolean copyFiles(String srcFilePath, String destinationFileName) throws Exception {
    boolean successful = false;
    SmbFileOutputStream sfos = null;

    try {
        String user = USER_NAME + ":" + PASSWORD;
        System.out.println("User: " + user);

        NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("mydomain",USER_NAME,PASSWORD);
        Config.setProperty("resolveOrder", "DNS");

        String destinationFilePath = NETWORK_FOLDER +"/" +destinationFileName;

        SmbFile sFile = new SmbFile(destinationFilePath, auth);
        sfos = new SmbFileOutputStream(sFile);
    // sfos.write(getBytesFromFile(new File(srcFilePath))); -- 1st approach
       // Files.copy(new File(srcFilePath).toPath(),sfos); -- 2nd approach
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(srcFilePath);

        BufferedReader brl = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
        String b = null;
        while ((b = brl.readLine()) != null) {
            sfos.write(b.getBytes());
        }
        sfos.flush();

        successful = true;
        System.out.println("Successful" + successful);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        successful = false;
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (sfos != null) {
            sfos.close();
        }
    }
    return successful;
}
```

It is taking more than 10 minutes to copy 10 mb file. Whereas when I copy the same file directly it is taking around 1 minute. I tried 3 approaches to copy the file (see the commented part of the code) but none of them showed any significant difference.

Is there anyway I can improve the performance of JCIFS?

Comment: Same problem. Deos anyone know any settings/workaround to speed up the file transfer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround I have mounted the shared drive and copied the file into that drive.